# How to calculate how many checkboxes are checked in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have 3 asp.net standard checkbox control and 1 textbox. I check 1 and 3 checkboxes. In textbox how to calculate how many checkboxes are checked? If I checked 1 then textbox result is 1. If I check 1,2 the textbox result is 2. If I check all checkboxes then the result is 3

How to do this in asp.net?

Comment: we need more information about what youve tried.

Comment: Why don't you do it in javascript? This isn't something that would warrant a trip to the server from what you've told us already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

its simple i assume that it is  checkbox control and  not checkboxlist

in your click event

```
protected void click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 
    int count=0;
    if(checkbox1.checked)
    {
        count ++;
    }
    if(checkbox2.checked)
    {
        count ++;
    }
    if(checkbox3.checked)
    {
        count ++;
    }

    textbox.text = count.ToString();
}
```

Comment: The indentation is absolutely horrid - why would you *do* that? =)

Comment: pardon i cant understand :p

Comment: ha ha ha really u r funny, i never care about indending even in my own coding :)

Comment: then tick it :) @MayankSharma

Answer (score 0):

Something Like :

```
textBox.Text = (from chkbox in Form.Controls.OfType<CheckBox>() select chkbox).Count(chked => chked.Checked).ToString();
```

Or

```
textBox.Text=Form.Controls.OfType<CheckBox>().Count(chked=>chked.Checked).ToString();
```